# Subversion : Why do my project in subversion "branches", "tags", "trunk", and "wiki" folders does not exist?

Tags: svn, tags, branch, trunk

I just created a project in subversion, but **why the folder branches, tags, trunk, and wiki does not exist** ?
I have checkout and commit some files, but these folders still not exist.
**How do I create these folder in my project** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those folders never get created automatically. You need to actually create them yourself like any other folder, by creating a folder in your working copy, adding it, and committing. Or, using the `svn mkdir` command with a URL.

Since you already created and committed files, you'll also need to `svn move` them to the correct folder.

I have no idea where the "wiki" folder came in...I've never seen that in the standard setup.

The fact that you're even asking this question shows a lack of basic understanding how SVN works. Stop right now, and read how SVN works: http://svnbook.red-bean.com